# Receive sip call using pjsip sipstack

Tags: android

I developing VOIP android application that make and receive the sip call.I Build the pjsip lilbrary as described in "http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android".

I use the pjsua sample application code for make sip call by using:

```
      MyCall call = new MyCall(account, -1);
      prm = new CallOpParam(true);
            try {
                call.makeCall("destination Sip Address", prm);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                call.delete();
                return;
            }
```

I am able to make Call but not able to receive call.What I do for receive sip call in my application?

Thanks.

Comment: To handle incoming Call in PJSIP, there is a method on_incoming_call in pjsua_app.c file. At First you want to registered in your account. Then incoming call came means, it reaches the method on_incoming_call. You want to pop up any notification into your app from there. To check incoming call, print any statements there in starting of that method.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was also testing those code samples on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS virtual machine with PJSIP 2.5.5 and got the same problem. Can make outgoing calls to my Asterisk server on a Raspberry Pi or to other clients (btw quality is not so perfect :/) and NO way to receive incoming calls.

I'm picking up SIP error 603

(from Wikipedia: "**603 Decline**
The destination does not wish to participate in the call, or cannot do so, and additionally the destination knows there are no alternative destinations (such as a voicemail server) willing to accept the call.")

and info from asterisk console, that user is busy.

Did you come up with something in that case??